# sed and grep instructions

Tags: windows-7, powershell, grep, sed

How can I run and test `sed` and `grep` instructions in `Windows PowerShell`?

When I run `Windows PowerShell`, and try to test `sed` instruction on my file, it gives the following error:

```
The term 'sed' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spellin
g of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ sed <<<<  -r "s/[0-9]/digit/"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sed:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am trying to run the following path/sed instruction:

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> cd sed -r "s/[0-9]/a" file.txt
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: sed is a specific command that's part of a common unix toolkit. It does not exist in windows by default

Comment: @Journeyman Geek♦, Do you mean it doesn't work on Windows at all?

Comment: See my answer. But no, unless you install a port

Comment: @Journeyman Geek♦, Would it work on Linux?

Comment: In most common distributions, absolutely

Comment: You don't need `sed` and `grep` in PowerShell when you have things like `Select-String` and the `-replace` operator.

Answer (score 1):

sed is a specific command that's part of a common unix/linux toolkit. It does not exist in windows by default

As such, on a stock windows system, these commands won't work in powershell or cmd.

I typically just install these myself (as part of the [GOW utilities](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow)).

There's [equivilents in powershell as well](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html) - match works vaguely like grep and replace works vaguely like sed, but I'm not familiar enough with these to give a more fleshed out set of examples.

Answer (score 0):

For a Microsoft Windows system, you can use the Windows versions of the [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) [GNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) utilities. An alternative means to access those utilities, if you have a Windows 10 system, is to [install the  Windows Subsystem for Linux](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win10/Linux-Subsystem/), which provides those tools as well as many other commonly used tools found on Linux/Unix systems, though the latter alternative would be providing access to those tools outside of PowerShell.

Comment: I tried some alternatives: see this article (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2007/07/08/grep-and-sed-with-powershell/). This  works.